# Arc Map 10.1 Identify tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, select, identify

I'm trying to identify features from multiple layers. For example, I have many locations around a river (within a 100 m buffer) which I would like to identify, but instead of having to draw rectangles around river segment and identifying many unnecessary locations, I would want to only identify locations which I had previously selected (by polygon or freehand).

Is this possible in ArcMap 10.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use [Select Layer By Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001700000072000000):

> Selects features in a layer based on a spatial relationship to
>   features in another layer.
>
> Each feature in the Input Feature Layer is evaluated against the
>   features in the Selecting Features layer or feature class; if the
>   specified Relationship is met, the input feature is selected.

Comment: ok, but what if one layer is linear feature, and other layer point feature? I want to identify all point features within 200 m buffer around a linear feature

Comment: The Select Layer by Location tool works with a single layer so you would need to run it as many times as you have layers next to your river layer.